# Snakemake: Wildcard in subworkflow

Tags: snakemake

I want to apply the same subworkflow to each of X subdirectories. Is there a way to use wildcards in subworkflows? Something like

```
subworkflow otherworkflow:
    workdir:
        "../{mypath}/otherworkflow"
    snakefile:
        "../path/to/otherworkflow/Snakefile"
    configfile:
        "../{mypath}/custom_configfile.yaml"

rule a:
    input:
        otherworkflow("../folder1/test.txt")
        otherworkflow("../folder2/test.txt")
    output: ...
    shell:  ...
```

Comment: You may hide the `{mypath}` into the subworkflow itself (defining a rule that produces the files in the directory described with a wildcard).

Comment: But this only works if the same configuration is used for every `{mypath}`, right?

Comment: yes, I got your idea. The subworkflow uses the same config.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to your problem? I would like my workdir to depend on a wildcard, such that I can simplify the paths in the subworkflow